# How to build a scatter graph in excel with average y value for each x value

Tags: excel, graph, average, scatter

I am not sure that here is the best place to ask,
but I have summerized my program performance data in an excel file and I want to build a scatter graph.
For each x value I have 6 y values and I want my graph to contain the average of those 6 to each x.
Is there a way to do this in excel?

For example: I have

X    Y

1   0.2

1   0

1   0

1   0.8

1   1.4

1   0

2   0.2

2   1.2

2   1

2   2.2

2   0

2   2.2

3   0.8
3   1.6
3   0
3   3.6
3   1.2
3   0.6

For each x I want my graph to contain the average y.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what you want but suggest inserting a column (assumed to be B) immediately between your two existing ones and populating it with:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,C:C)
```

then plotting X against those values.

Or maybe better, just subtotal for each change in X with average for Y and plot that.